# $ \ddot{x} + x - x^2 = 0$, time elapsed between phase path points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Not homework, but voluntarily solving excercise from textbook. First, find equilibrium points and general phase equation for the system

$$ \ddot{x}  + x - x^2 = 0$$

First I get equilibrium points $(0,0)$ and (1,0). With $ y = \dot{x}$ and $\dot{y} = f(x,y)$, the general phase equation from the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{f(x,y)}{y}$ is calculated by me as

$$ y(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}x^3 - x^2 + C} $$

prefereably with $C < 1$ to keep $y$ real(?).

Thereafter: find the transit time $T_{AB}$ between the given points on the phase path $A:=(-0.5,0)$ and $B := (0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$ from the equation

$$ \int_{AB} \frac{dx}{y(x)} $$

The given answer is $2\tanh^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$, but the integral seem way too messy to solve.

Is my phase equation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cubic factors as $(2x+1)(x-1)^2/3$.  So you can integrate it by substituting $u=\sqrt{2x+1}$.

Comment: thanks! Your factors expands to $\frac{2}{3}x^3 - x^2 + \frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: That is the right $C$ for both $(-1/2,0)$ and $(0,1/\sqrt{3})$

Comment: ok thanks again!